# string.contains() vs string.equals() or string == performance

Tags: c#, string, performance

I'm returning a string from an API that has a length of 45 characters.  There is one word that is unique for one condition that doesn't appear in the other condition.

I'm wondering if using string.contains() is faster performance-wise than comparing the whole string with string.equals() or string == "blah blah".

I don't know the inner workings of any of these methods, but logically, it seems like contains() should be faster because it can stop traversing the string after it finds the match.  Is this accurate?  Incidentally, the word I want to check is the first word in the string.

Comment: `Contains` and `Equals` are not equivalent and not interchangable.

Comment: "the word I want to check is the first word in the string" - sounds like you want `StartsWith` then, right?

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem?  I ask because this is almost always over optimization.  Considering it's an API call, I wouldn't even care which is the most *performant*.  (But I would care which is functionally correct)

Comment: Can you give examples of what you are comparing.  It doesn't even sound like `Equals` or `==` would make sense if you are looking to do sub-string matching (which is what `Contains` does).

Comment: if you are concerned about the performance, I would recommend this 
http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-occurs-within-a-string

however, you should know your requirements first, do you want to know if one string is contained in another or if two strings are equal ;)

Comment: wow...not sure why all the down votes, seems like a legit question. @tnw why not ask the experts first, if someone already has the knowledge, why not leverage that option...isn't that what SO is for?

Comment: @BlairHolmes I downvoted because your question clearly shows no research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with D Stanley (comment). You should use [String.StartsWith()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith(v=vs.110).aspx)

That said, I also don't know the inner working of each method either, but I can see your logic. However "String.Contains()" may still load the entire string before processing it, in which case the performance difference would be very small.

As a final point, with a string length of only 45 characters, the performance difference should me extremely minute. I was shocked when I wrote a junky method to substitute characters and found that is processes ~10kb of text in a fraction of a blink of the eye. So unless you're doing some crazy handling else wise in your app, it shouldn't matter much.